# Managed switch not contactable when plugged in to Fortigate 30E

Tags: networking, firewall, dhcp, switch, fortigate

I just bought a UniFi US-8 (8 port managed PoE switch) and I'm trying to set it up, but I can't get the UniFi controller to see the device; the controller just says "No devices found."

My current network setup is:

ISP modem/router (`192.168.0.1/24`) -> Fortigate 30E (`192.168.1.1/24`) -> Desktop (`192.168.1.10/24`)

The UniFi controller is installed on my desktop (`192.168.1.10/24`).

If I remove the Fortigate ate from the equation:

1. Reconfigure my ISP modem/router to be on the `192.168.1.0/24` network
2. Connect the switch and my desktop each to a LAN port on the modem/router

I can then contact (ping/ssh) the switch from my desktop (`192.168.1.10/24`), and the controller running on my desktop sees the switch, and can "adopt" it.

However, if I put the Fortigate gate back into the equation:

1. ISP modem/router on the `192.168.0.0/24` network
2. Fortigate 30E on the `192.168.1.0/24` network (WAN port plugged into a LAN port on the ISP router)
3. Desktop and switch plugged in to LAN ports on the Fortigate

My desktop can no longer see the switch. Looking at the device inventory in the Fortigate, it looks like the switch does get a DHCP lease for `192.168.1.12/24`, but I can only get to this address if I plug a laptop directly into the switch and configure the laptop to be on the `192.168.1.0/24` network.

Is the Fortigate doing something to block traffic to the switch? If so, what can I do to allow the traffic to flow?

For reference, the output of the `show system interface` command is below:

```
FWF30E********** # show system interface
config system interface
    edit "wan"
        set vdom "root"
        set ip 192.168.0.10 255.255.255.0
        set allowaccess ping https http fgfm
        set type physical
        set scan-botnet-connections block
        set role wan
        set snmp-index 1
    next
    edit "modem"
        set vdom "root"
        set mode pppoe
        set type physical
        set snmp-index 2
    next
    edit "ssl.root"
        set vdom "root"
        set type tunnel
        set alias "SSL VPN interface"
        set snmp-index 3
    next
    edit "wifi"
        set vdom "root"
        set type vap-switch
        set role lan
        set snmp-index 5
    next
    edit "guestwifi"
        set vdom "root"
        set ip 192.168.11.1 255.255.255.0
        set allowaccess ping https ssh http
        set type vap-switch
        set device-identification enable
        set fortiheartbeat enable
        set role lan
        set snmp-index 7
    next
    edit "internal"
        set vdom "root"
        set ip 192.168.1.1 255.255.255.0
        set allowaccess ping https ssh http fgfm capwap
        set broadcast-forward enable
        set type switch
        set device-identification enable
        set fortiheartbeat enable
        set role lan
        set snmp-index 6
    next
    edit "lan"
        set vdom "root"
        set type hard-switch
        set stp enable
        set role lan
        set snmp-index 4
    next
end
```

Comment: Can your _other_ devices reach each other while being connected to the Fortigate's LAN ports? Do they end up on the same 192.168.1.0/24 subnet? Can they receive ARP responses directly from each other (and not fake ones from Fortigate)?

Comment: Hi @grawity, yes they can. I have another physical machine (192.168.1.200/24) which is also plugged into a LAN port on the fortigate - my desktop can talk to it and vice versa. How can I test that the ARP responses are "true" and not ones being "faked" by the fortigate?

Comment: Check whether their ARP cache (`arp -a` or similar) shows the opposite device's MAC address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I think I solved the problem - below are my notes:

I noticed if I reboot the firewall, shortly before it finishes booting, the switch begins adopting. As soon as the firewall finishes booting, the switch loses connection. I also can't contact any other devices on my subnet.

If I remove "lan" from the members of the default "internal" software switch, the switch (still defaulting to 192.168.1.20/24) connects to my desktop (and I can connect to other devices on the 192.168.1.0/24 network), but I lose internet connectivity. The firewall automatically creates a new hardware switch interface called "lan", comprised of all 4 physical LAN interfaces as member interfaces.

To connect back to the firewall from my desktop, I had to log in to 192.168.1.99 (the firewall's IP) with my phone (which is on the 192.168.1.0/24 internal wifi network), and set the new "lan" gateway IP to 192.168.10.99/24, then set my computer to be on the new subnet (I set it to 192.168.10.10/24, with gateway 192.168.10.99). But, now because my desktop is on a different subnet, I lose connection to the switch.

From my desktop (192.168.10.10/24, gateway 192.168.10.99), I created a new firewall rule in "IPv4 policy" to allow all traffic from "lan" to "wan". This reconnected me to the internet, but as expected I can't ping it or SSH to the switch or any other hosts on the 192.168.1.0/24 network. I confirmed this by setting my desktop back to the 192.168.1.0/24 network (gateway 192.168.1.99), which kills my internet, but I can ping/SSH to other hosts in that subnet once more, and the switch reconnects.

Given I know the switch defaults to 192.168.1.20/24 if it doesn't get a DHCP lease, I turned the DHCP server on for the "lan" interface, and the switch finally got assigned an IP, and connected to my desktop.

Now the next problem was to find out how to enable devices on the "internal" interface (wifi devices) to communicate with devices on the "lan" interface (wired devices). To do this I set up 2 IPv4 policies: allow all traffic from "lan" to "internal", and allow all traffic from "internal" to "lan".

This solution achieves the desired result, but I'm not sure it's the most secure way (or the "best" way) of achieving it.